# JVM. Что происходит со ссылками на объекты при их перемещении в Tenured?

Tags: java, jvm, сборщик-мусора

Чем дольше живут объекты в **java** тем больше вероятность того, что они будут жить и дальше, поэтому для ускорения работы **сборщика мусора** куча поделена на **Eden** и **Tenured** *(как я понимаю)*. Вопрос, что происходит со ссылками на объекты, которые были перемещены в oldGen, Что произойдет при обращении к объекту который в данный момент перемещается?

Comment: Уточните, за какой метод сборки мусора идет речь. Их там минимум 4. При сборке мусора обычно приложение останавливается полностью. Но это опять же зависит от метода

Comment: Ну принцип последовательного сборщика как я понимаю: Приложение останавливается, gc выполняет свою работу, ссылки на перемещенные объекты меняются. А на счет параллельного вообще не понимаю: возможна ли ситуация, когда ссылка приведет к, так сказать, старому адресу расположения объекта, типо состояние гонки в многопоточном приложении?

Comment: Нет, невозможна. У параллельных сборщиков тоже есть stop the world, только менее продолжительные. Сборщики без пауз используют сложные алгоритмы и методы синхронизации для обеспечения целостности ссылок.